# Cloning a git repo using SSH

Tags: git, ssh

I am trying to clone a git repository using SSH. Therefore, I created an ssh key pair on my local machine and I added the public key on my git repo(which is Bitbucket server).

Then, as I saw [here](https://kuttler.eu/en/post/git-clone-ssh-could-not-resolve-hostname/), I tried cloning like this:

```
git clone ssh://my_username@my-repository.com:7999/my_project.git

git clone ssh://git@my-repository.com:7999/my_project.git
```

These options didn't work however:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

The only bit of progress I has was by trying this:

```
git clone my_username@my-repository.com:7999/my_project.git
```

This asked for my password 3 times and then failed. I suspect that this doesn't use SSH though, 
            because I think SSH should not ask for a password.

```
Password:
Password:
Password:
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,keyboard-interactive).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

So how can I clone a git repo using SSH?

**EDIT**

I'm on Windows and I'm using Git Bash.

```
ssh-add -l
```

Returns

```
The agent has no identities.
```

Comment: Bitbucket *private* server or the cloud hosting server?

Comment: What OS -- Windows? Linux?  OSX?

Comment: @patricksteele Windows. I updated the question.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Bitbucket PRIVATE server

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that ssh on this host works on port 7990? If this repo is on bitbucket, then I'm almost sure that you cane use default port for ssh

```
git clone my_username@my-repository.com/my_project.git
```

just like in [git with bitbucket](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-the-ssh-protocol-with-bitbucket-cloud-221449711.html)

Comment: The Bitbucket server is on `7990`. I found somewhere in the code a git ssh command using `7999`. I tried both ports, with no success.

Comment: did you check this guide: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bbkb/permission-denied-publickey-302811860.html ?

Answer (score 2):

Most servers will expect users to authenticate with the 'git' username, and their own private key which is used for identification purposes.

Just try connecting with SSH:

```sh
ssh ${USERNAME}@${SERVER} -p ${PORT}
```

This will establish if you're able to even authenticate against the server, removing git from the equation.

Where is your private key? If it isn't `~/.ssh/id_rsa` (or a configured path), then you'll need to provide it's path. Try this:

```sh
ssh ${USERNAME}@${SERVER} -p ${PORT} -i ${MY_PRIVATE_KEY}
```

If this works, then you can setup your SSH configuration to be more conveniant.
In `~/.ssh/config` you can put something like this:

```
Host ${FRIENDLY_NAME}
    User ${USERNAME}
    Hostname ${SERVER}
    Port ${PORT}
    IdentityFile ${MY_PRIVATE_KEY}
```

You can then test the connection like so:

```
ssh ${FRIENDLY_NAME}
```

And finally:

```
git clone ssh://${FRIENDLY_NAME}/${REPO_PATH}
```

You'll only need to specify the port if it isn't the default (22).

NOTE: I've used tilde (`~`) because you hadn't specified Windows when I wrote my answer. You can find out your 'home' directory on Windows by pressing Win+R, entering a dot `.`, and pressing return. This will typically take you to `C:\Users\%USERNAME%`

Comment: For `ssh ${USERNAME}@${SERVER} -p ${PORT} -i ${MY_PRIVATE_KEY}`, I get `shell request failed on channel 0`.

Comment: Success! not a very friendly one, but still.